# Add in a javascript function a Php Request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to add a line which allows me to send a request to `add.php`.

As soon as we click on this function, we give also a request via the page `add.php?id=1`

```
$('.js-addcart-b1').each(function(){
        var nameProduct = $(this).parent().parent().find('.js-name-b1').html();
        $(this).on('click', function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
            swal(nameProduct, "is added to cart !", "success");
        });
    });
```

Where should I put the command in method [GET]?

Comment: There is no request made in your code

Comment: @Luca I think that is what the OP is asking about but weren't clear. @OP, take a look at [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: where is the `id` coming from ?

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0):

To send a request to the server (`add.php?id=1`) you should use `jQuery's ajax()` method:

```
var productId = 1; // hardcoded, only for example!

$.ajax({
    url: "add.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: {id: productId},
    success: function(result){

        swal(nameProduct, "is added to cart !", "success");
    },
    error: function(error){

        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Full code with your example below:

```js
$('.js-addcart-b1').each(function(){

   var nameProduct = $(this).parent().parent().find('.js-name-b1').html();

   $(this).on('click', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        
        var productId = 1; // hardcoded, only for example!

        $.ajax({
            url: "add.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: {id: productId},
            success: function(result){

                swal(nameProduct, "is added to cart !", "success");
            },
            error: function(error){

                console.log(error);
            }
        });
   });
});
```

In your example there's a `GET` request, I suggest you to use `POST` for sensitive data, it's more secure. As others suggested you need to get the `id` from somewhere in your `HTML` to pass it to the server.

[More information about jQuery ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp)

Comment: where are you sending the product `id` ?

Comment: Where is `productId` defined?

Comment: @tamasSzoke you are so good !! thank you so much. If I want to change the value var productId = 1; // hardcoded, only for example! from my add.php?id=.....    How do I replace 1 with any other value ?

Comment: You're welcome, simply replace it with any other number, but you should get the id like you did for nameProduct.

Comment: Yes, this script was on main.js. I had to put it on my php file in order to put the variable in php . otherwise I would have had no idea to put a variable on my js file.

Comment: Yes, first you need to set the ids on php, then get them with js (like nameProduct).